# Vector calculus in Electromagnetism

Tags: electromagnetism, differentiation, notation, vector-fields

I found a problem which had  $$\partial_i (A_j \vec{G})= (\vec{\nabla} .\vec{ A} )\vec{G}+ (\vec{A}.\nabla) \vec{G} $$ but my problem is what does   $$\partial_i (A_j \vec{B})$$ even mean? it doesn't look like $(\vec{\nabla} .\vec{ A} )\vec{G} $ neither does it looks like $\nabla (\vec{A}.\vec{B})$ So what is it in terms of $\nabla $.

Source: Problem 1.11 Modern Electromagantism by Zangwill

Comment: The first term not make sense at all, there are two free index and in the other side of the identity there is not index. Could you please post the complete exercise from the book to check this?

Comment: Must be a Typo. It should be $\sum_i \partial_i A_i \vec G$ The summation may be omitted by convention.

Comment: @SHIN101 It is inappropriate to make edits to a question which invalidate existing answers. If you have follow-up questions, ask them in a new thread.

Comment: To begin with, the number of free indices on the LHS & RHS do not match.

Answer (score 6):

The 'identity' you're quoting is incorrect $-$ and, even more, it makes no sense at all to begin with.

The object on the left-hand side can be expanded as
$$
\partial_i (A_j \vec G) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left(A_j(\vec x) \vec G(\vec x)\right),
$$
where $A_j(\vec x)$ is the $j$th component of the vector field $\vec A(\vec x)$. This object has two free indices, $i$ and $j$, and thus it cannot equal the right-hand side, which has no free indices.

To calculate it, you simply use the product rule. This is most easily done by splitting $$\vec G(\vec x) = \sum_k G_k(\vec x) \hat{\mathbf{e}}_k = \sum_k G_k \hat{\mathbf{e}}_k$$ into its components (dropping the explicit $\vec x$ dependence for simplicity from here onwards), so you get
\begin{align}
\partial_i (A_j \vec G) 
& = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left(A_j \sum_k G_k \hat{\mathbf{e}}_k\right)
\\ & = \sum_k \hat{\mathbf{e}}_k \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left(A_j G_k \right)
\\ & = \sum_k \hat{\mathbf{e}}_k \left( \frac{\partial A_j}{\partial x_i} G_k + A_j\frac{\partial G_k}{\partial x_i}  \right)
\\& = \frac{\partial A_j}{\partial x_i}\vec G + A_j\frac{\partial \vec G}{\partial x_i}
,
\end{align}
which can also be notated $(\partial_i A_j)\vec G + A_j\partial_i \vec G$, but that's as far as you can go.

**However**, things get more interesting if you change the left-hand side of your original expression so that (i) both indices are the same, and (ii) you add a summation over that index. If you do this, you get the result
$$
\sum_i \partial_i (A_i \vec G) 
= \sum_i \frac{\partial A_i}{\partial x_i}\vec G + \sum_i A_i\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i} \vec G,
$$
and here we can see additional structure:

- $\sum_i \frac{\partial A_i}{\partial x_i} = \nabla\cdot\vec A$ is simply the divergence of the vector field $\vec A$, and
- $\sum_i A_i\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i} = (\vec A\cdot \nabla)$ is the [directional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative) of $\vec G$ along $\vec A$.

This is what you have on the right-hand side of your original expression.

So, what's going on? Most likely, you've mistranscribed the left-hand side of your original expression, which likely read
$$
\partial_i (A_i \vec{G})= ({\nabla} \cdot\vec{ A} )\vec{G}+ (\vec{A}\cdot\nabla) \vec{G} 
$$
in its original source. The key difference here is that both of the indices are the same, and this then implies that the source is using the [Einstein summation convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) (discussed by Zangwill in §1.2.4), i.e., the convention that any repeated indices must be summed over (and are therefore no longer *free* indices). In that form, the expression is correct.

Comment: yeah thanks it was a mistake on my part , I corrected it. Still I dont get how would I integrate it over  volume

Comment: Since the LHS uses components (indices and summation), while the RHS uses 3 D vectors, I would say the expression is inconsistent: either one uses index notation throughout, or vector notation throughout in equalities.

Comment: @SHIN101 There is no mention of integration in the original question. If you want to ask an expanded question, start a new thread.

Comment: ... though I can give you *one* hint here (for more, start a new thread). For the integral in Zangwill's problem 1.11, separate the surface integral into individual components (i.e. as $\hat{\mathbf e}_j \int_S x_j \vec P \cdot \mathrm d\vec S$) and apply the divergence theorem to get a volume integral of $\nabla\cdot (x_j \vec P)=\partial_i(x_jP_i)$, and then simplify as appropriate.

Comment: I am new here so i'll  a new thread.Thanks for help tho

Comment: @DanielC I think that is an artificial rule that doesn't really make sense. Otherwise one wouldn't be able to write things like $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E} = \sum_i \partial_i E_i$